# Meter links desde textarea

Tags: php

Mediante dos `textarea` estoy intentando meter links y el nombre de dichas paginas de una sola tirada en vez de ir de uno en uno.

```
foreach ($titleAr as $titleLine) {
    foreach ($linkAr as $linkLine) {
        $result = insert(trim($titleLine), trim($linkLine));
    }
}
```

Con dos `foreach` me mete para cada titulo todos los links y yo lo que quiero es el primero con el primero, segundo con el segundo, etc...

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español! Te animo a leerte [ask] para aprender a realizar buenas preguntas que sean mejor aceptadas por la comunidad, y de paso haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y ganarte tu primera medalla! En este caso, a tu pregunta le faltan datos de ejemplo con los que podamos reproducir tu error y responderte adecuadamente. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta de nuevo agregándolos para que sea un [example] válido. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si son arrays paralelos basta con tu primer foreach  y una variable contadora que vaya iterando tus posiciones del segundo array

```
$i=0;
foreach ($titleAr as $titleLine) { 
  $result = insert(trim($titleLine), trim($linkAr[$i]));
  $i++;
}
```